# phaser drag and drop on multiple text items

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In a game I want to add the numbers 1-9 that are draggable, and on the drag and drop events I want to call some functions. But in a loop events are not working. Any solution will be nice.

Here is the code:

```
var count = 0;
points.forEach(function(item){
    var one = game.add.text(item.centerX, item.centerY, count, this.style);
    one.anchor.setTo(0.5)
    one.inputEnabled = true;
    one.input.enableDrag();
    one.input.startDrag(game.input.activePointer);
    one.events.onInputDown.add(this.clone, this, 0, one);
    one.events.onDragStop.add(this.fixLocation);
    count++;
});
```

This gives me the error:

> Phaser.Signal: listener is a required param of add() and should be a Function.

this is the `fixlocation` function

```
fixLocation: function(item){

         if(rectangle.contains(item.x, item.y)){
            itemAdded += 1;
        } else{
            item.destroy()
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `clone` and `fixLocation` are functions? The error is suggesting that one of them is not https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Signal.html#add

Comment: I have defined those functions

Comment: When i use the same logic outside loop, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

My fault. Acutally the `this` inside `foreach` in in wrong context. It is the inside of the loop. All i have to do was to call function outside of the loop. that is:

```
var count = 0;
            var me = this;// get this here
            points.forEach(function(item){
                var one = game.add.text(item.centerX, item.centerY, count, this.style);
                one.anchor.setTo(0.5)
                one.inputEnabled = true;
                one.input.enableDrag();
                one.input.startDrag(game.input.activePointer);
                one.events.onInputDown.add(me.clone, this, 0, one); // now call the function
                one.events.onDragStop.add(me.fixLocation);
                count++;
            })
```